PackageSourceMapping error when packagereference exists and is installed
I'm unable to run a dotnet project on Visual Studio Community 2022 that is currently working on other team members' local machines.
I have Net8.0 installed and the .csproj has the packageReference.
   <PackageReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.3.0" />

I'm getting the same error for all the package references. I have no idea how to resolve these errors and my boss is also at a loss.
Error   NU1100  Unable to resolve 'dotnet-xunit (>= 2.3.1)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: gitlab, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org.    ProjectName.Tests   C:\PATH/ProjectName.Tests.csproj    1   

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks
